# RPi: one common network between Wi-Fi module and Ethernet

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dhcp, dnsmasq

So, I have Raspberry Pi B+. And compatible (I have checked, it worked) Wi-Fi module for RPi. I use Raspbian.

My task is build a router from RPi (with Wi-Fi access point).

But, one important detail there.
I *don't need* internet access on this setup.
This setup will only give us communication between Wi-Fi (1 or more) and Ethernet (1) clients.

For example, in this LAN:

- 192.168.1.1 - is RPi itself
- 192.168.1.10 - Ethernet client
- 192.168.1.15 - Wi-Fi client #1
- 192.168.1.20 - Wi-Fi client #2
- ...

How to build router on RPi, which works without internet by scheme described above?

Thank you for your help! If you have questions, feel free to ask, please.

Comment: So what's the question ?

Comment: @TimF How to build router on RPi, which works without internet by scheme described above?

Comment: You are probably looking for the two packages `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`.

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank you! https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67862/pi-one-common-network-between-wi-fi-module-and-ethernet